# Django login authentication not working

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-authentication, django-generic-views

I am trying to use the generic login view provided by Django. i want the registration and login form on the same page. Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myApp.forms import UsersForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'templates/login.html', 'authentication_form':UsersForm}),
)
```

and this is my login.html

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ authentication_form.first_name }} {{authentication_form.last_name }} <br>
        {{ authentication_form.username }} {{ authentication_form.password }} <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>


    {% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
            {{ error | striptags }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">{% csrf_token%}
        {{authentication_form.username.label_tag}}
        {{authentication_form.username}}
        {{authentication_form.password.label_tag}}
        {{authentication_form.password}}
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the server and go to 127.0.0.1, only the login and register Buttons show up, the actual fields do not (I can't type anything in anywhere on the page, there are just two buttons, one which says 'login' and another which says 'register'. There is just a blank white space where the actual fields should be. How come the box for username, password, first name and last name aren't showing up?

EDIT: when I change authentication_form.username to just form.username, it gives a template error saying

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and the traceback to this is

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  140.                     response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  87.             output = force_text(output)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  99.                 s = s.__unicode__()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  411.         return self.as_widget()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  458.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in value
  494.                 self.data, self.form.initial.get(self.name, self.field.initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _data
  480.         return self.field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.form.data, self.form.files, self.html_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in value_from_datadict
  209.         return data.get(name, None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My generic login view is just this

```
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
      redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
      authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
      current_app=None, extra_context=None):
"""
Displays the login form and handles the login action.
"""
redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

if request.method == "POST":
    form = authentication_form(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
        if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
            redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
        auth_login(request, form.get_user())

        if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            request.session.delete_test_cookie()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
else:
    form = authentication_form(request)

request.session.set_test_cookie()

current_site = get_current_site(request)

context = {
    'form': form,
    redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
    'site': current_site,
    'site_name': current_site.name,
}
if extra_context is not None:
    context.update(extra_context)
return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                        current_app=current_app)
```

I didn't make any changes to template_name (although I did specify template_name in my urls.py which can be seen above) or current_app. My form class in forms.py is this

```
class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
model = Users
widgets = {'password':forms.PasswordInput()}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super( UsersForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields[ 'first_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="First Name"  
    self.fields[ 'last_name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Last Name"
    self.fields[ 'username' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Username"
    self.fields[ 'password' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Password"
    self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your First Name.', 'max_length': 'Your First Name must be shorter than 50 characters.'}
    self.fields['last_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your Last Name.', 'max_length': 'Your last Name must be shorter than 50 characters.'}
    self.fields['password'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a Password.', 'max_length': 'Your Password must be shorter than 50 characters.', 'invalid': 'Your Password can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens.'}
    self.fields['username'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a Username.', 'max_length': 'Your Username must be shorter than 50 characters.', 'invalid': 'Your Username can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens.',}

def clean_date_of_birth_month(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth_month')
    if data == 'Month':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a correct Month for your date of birth.')

    return data

def clean_date_of_birth_day(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth_day')
    if data == 'Day':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a correct Day for your date of birth.')

    return data

def clean_date_of_birth_year(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth_year')
    if data == 'Year':
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a correct Year for your date of birth.')

    return data
```

It is a form created from an existing model, which is this

```
class Users(models.Model): 
    months = (
    ('Month','Month'), ('January', 'January'), ('February','February'), ('March','March'), ('April','April'), ('May','May'), ('June','June'), 
    ('July','July'), ('August','August'), ('September','September'), ('October','October'), ('November','November'), ('December','December'),
)

    days = (
    ('Day', 'Day'), ('1','1'), ('2','2'), ('3','3'), ('4','4'), ('5','5'), ('6','6'), ('7','7'), ('8','8'), ('9','9'), ('10','10'), ('11','11'),
    ('12','12'), ('13','13'), ('14','14'), ('15','15'), ('16','16'), ('17','17'), ('18','18'), ('19','19'), ('20','20'), ('21','21'), ('22','22'),
    ('23','23'), ('24','24'), ('25','25'), ('26','26'), ('27','27'), ('28','28'), ('29','29'), ('30','30'),('31','31'),
)

    years = (
('Year','Year'), ('2013','2013'), ('2012','2012'), ('2011','2011'), ('2010','2010'), ('2009','2009'), ('2008','2008'),
)

    alpha_field = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', message='Name can only contain letters.')

    user_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[alpha_field]) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[alpha_field])

    username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, error_messages={'unique': u'A user with that Username already exists. Please choose a different Username.'})
    password = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    date_of_birth_month = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=9, choices=months, default='Month')
    date_of_birth_day = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=3, choices=days, default='Day')
    date_of_birth_year = models.CharField(verbose_name='', max_length=4, choices=years, default='Year')
```

Comment: did you import usersform in urls.py

Comment: @binboavetonik yes in my urls.py I did "from myApp.forms import UsersForm"

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
{{form.username}}
```

because generic view names it that way:

```
form = authentication_form(request)
```

Comment: Hm okay I changed it to form.username but now it gives a "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'" error highlighting {{form.username}} .. Do note that I didn't make any changes to the generic login view at all. was I supposed to? I edited my post with the traceback to the new error and what my generic login view looks like.

Comment: you should check your form class. Could you add the form code

Comment: sure, I just put up the UsersForm.

Comment: could u try removing  "init" at all from the usersForm

Comment: you mean remove the entire def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): function?

Comment: hm, it still gives the same "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'" error.. any other ideas why it is happening?

Comment: hm wait, so what do you think the problem is? What should my new question be? Why am I getting the error?